# i want to display the sum of salary in the text box of a company form , below the form we can also create new employee (name,role,dob,salary)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBNj4.png)at first we create a company by asking user to enter required info after that last 2 form fields are total employee count and total salary which are auto filled once we fill the required details of employee which contain (name,DOB,role,salary) also we can add multiple employees by clicking the '+' button beside the first row (new empty row will appear below the first row),so how can we get total salary for given employee field and display total salary in the company form above which has the Totalsalary field by using jquery

```
 this is the code i tried 

 $('.Salary').last.change(function () {
                $('.Salary').each(function () {
                    Totalsalary = parseInt(Totalsalary) + parseInt($('.Salary').val());`enter code here`
                    console.log(Totalsalary);
                    $('.Totalsalary').val(Totalsalary);
                    
                });

                Totalsalary = 0;
            });
```

Comment: you question is not clear what you want. please add relevant code where you face issue

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If  the class of the
salary inputs is `Salary`,here is a sample demo,calculating the salary when page loads and when the data of Salary inputs changes:

html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Salary</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="number" class="Salary" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="number" class="Salary" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="number" class="Salary" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

js:

```
<script>
        $(".Salary").change(function () {
        calcualteSalary();
    })
    function calcualteSalary() {
        var Totalsalary = 0;
        $('.Salary').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() != "") {
                Totalsalary += parseInt($(this).val());
            }
        });
        $('.Totalsalary').val(Totalsalary);
    }
    $(function () {
        calcualteSalary();
    })
</script>
```

result:

[image]